# Dynamic width size problem in UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell

I dynamically set width of each cell of `UICollectionView` according to text inside it. The problem is that most of the time the `width` size is correct but sometimes cell size is not correct.

These are strings i displayed in cell

```
let tabs = ["1st tab", "Second Tab Second", "Third Tab", "4th Tab", "A"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let text = tabs[indexPath.row]

    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 21, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
    let attributes = font != nil ? [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font] : [:]
    let width = text.size(withAttributes: attributes).width

    return CGSize(width: width + 16+16+16+35, height: self.menuBarColView.frame.height)

}
```

It correctly displayed 1st, second, third and 5th one but size of 4th cell is wrong. This is the output.

[image]

Please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Set the `estimatedItemSize` to (1, 1) somewhere before returning the actual size:
`(collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)`

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Thank you very much. It solved my problem.

Comment: I wrote an answer about it. Check it out. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selfsize collection view cell checklist:

- Set `estimated item size` to anything but `.zero`. Works best if you set it to (1,1)

example:

```
(collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
```

- Layout cell contents and check if it works if scalable content changes.
- Return the actual size if you can calculate it without loosing performance
- Double check to reduce codes that repeats and cache sizes.

---

If you are targeting iOS 10 and above, you can use this instead:

```
....estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the pictures cause of my VPN and I see that you fixed the problem, however, I want to add something, If your cells use auto layout and have constraints you need to calculate and change them too.