# iOS - dynamically size width of a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am just trying to dynamically size cells. I followed a few SO Questions and cannot seem to produce the same results.
[Example one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223869/how-to-make-dynamic-width-of-the-uicollectionviewcell/39224811)
[Example two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930787/dynamic-width-size-problem-in-uicollectionview-cell)

My code right now is:

```
extension ItemViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let text = allTags[indexPath.item]
        tagName.text = text //label from my custom cell (xCode not recognizing)
        return CGRect(width: tagName.intrinsicContentSize.width + 60, height: 40)
}
}
```

In the second line, tagName is not identified by Xcode. It is part of my custom cell class. The first SO question I linked somehow was able to identify their cell properties within sizeForItemAt. How would I do that to dynamically size my cells? I do have estimated size to non-nil:

```
if let collectionViewLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
}
```

My desired result in similar to the photos. Let me know if you need more info. Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with This Way.
it's working fine for me in Swift5.

First Implement **Collectionview FlowLayout Delegate**

```
extension ItemViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let text = "Your Lable Text"
        let font: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Font Name", size: 20) ??  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0) // set here font name and font size
        let width = text.SizeOf(font).width
        return CGSize(width: width + 20.0 , height: 40.0) // ADD width + space between text (for ex : 20.0)
        }    
}
```

Add One **String Extension**.

```
extension String {
    
    func SizeOf(_ font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        return self.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font])
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = UILabel.textWidth(font: UIFont(name: "pass same font name used in label", size: 12.0) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:
12.0), text: dataArray(indexPath.item))
        return CGSize(width: width + 20, height: 50)
    }

extension UILabel {
class func textWidth(font: UIFont, text: String) -> CGFloat {
      let myText = text as NSString
      let rect = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
      let labelSize = myText.boundingRect(with: rect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
      return ceil(labelSize.width)
  }
}
```

Comment: pass same font name and font size you are using for your label